# Can I use more than one findAll() in same api on same table to get the data?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I've created an api in which I've used a table called 'Hotels' and specified routes to get the data from it. I've given findAll() to get all the hotels' list and given one more findAll() to get the list of hotels which are having status as inactive (status is a column of the table). Now the problem is, only one findAll() is been executing in both the cases. Can't I use more than one findAll()? I've used Sequelize ORM with Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

you can write it as :

```
getHotels(status) { if(status === 'Inactive'){ return db.Hotels.findAll ({ where: {status: 'Inactive'}, raw:true }); } return db.Hotels.findAll(); }
```